# How to import data from Azure to R faster

Tags: r, azure, data.table, azure-sql-database, bigdata

I'm dealing with a huge database (67mi of rows and 55 columns). This database is on Azure and I want to make analysis in R with that. So I'm using the following:

```
library("odbc")
library("DBI")
library("tidyverse")
library("data.table")

con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
                      UID = rstudioapi::askForPassword("myEmail"),
                      Driver="ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                      Server = server, Database = database,
                      Authentication = "ActiveDirectoryInteractive")

#selecting columns
myData = data.table::setDT(DBI::dbGetQuery(conn = con, statement = 
                                       'SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
                                        FROM myTable'))
```

I'm trying to use `data.table::setDT` to convert the data.frame to data.base, but it is still taking a very long time to load.

Any hint on how can I load this data faster?

Comment: Unless you are plotting, it will be advisable to use the dataset while still in the database. Use SQL for the analysis you want. I am not sure what to do when plotting is involved

Comment: I will need  plot in some analyses. About using SQL for other analyses, can I do it inside `DBI ::dbGetQuery` like I did above to select the columns?

Comment: Running `setDT` around `dbGetQuery` does nothing to mitigate the long download time. `DBI` is great, but it is not fast with gobs of data; with SQL Server and similar DBMSes, I have always found the use of `sqlcmd` (command-line, non-R utility) to be significantly faster for larger data. It has its issues, though, starting with not being strictly CSV-compatible, but the issues can generally be worked-around.

Comment: (Having said that, I don't have access to an Azure instance, so I can only speculate if `sqlcmd` will connect to it.)

Comment: dump data to CSV outside of R and the import CSV